# When I edit a single record into a template by use django form it is not edited

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two models child and academy by which these two models have relationship to each other

here is child models

```
from django.db import models
class Child_detail(models.Model):
    Firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Tribe = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Firstname
```

Here is academy model

```
from django.db import models
from child.models import Child_detail
class Academic(models.Model):
    Student_name = models.ForeignKey(Child_detail,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Class = models.CharField(max_length =  50)
    Average_grade = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Student_name)
```

Here is my views.py file that contain ***edit*** functionality,into the template it does not show the fields to edit so i have to write those fields again and even that it does not edit anything

```
def edit_academy(request,pk):
    child=get_object_or_404(Child_detail,pk=pk)
    form = AcademicForm(instance=child)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=AcademicForm(request.POST,instance=child)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('more',pk=pk)
    context={
        'form':form,
        'child':child
    }    
    return render(request,'functionality/edit.html',context)
```

Here is my template file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<section id="register" class="bg-light py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
            <h4>
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Edit {{child.Firstname | title}} {{child.Lastname | title}} Academic Details </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              {{form | crispy}}
              <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </section>

{% endblock %}
```

And here is my Academic form file

```
class AcademicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Academic
        fields='Class','Date','Average_grade','Overall_position','Total_number_in_class'
        labels={
            'Average_grade':'Average Grade',
            'Overall_position':'Overall Position',
            'Total_number_in_class':'Total Number In Class'
        }
```

Comment: Please post your template. Also, while Edgardo Obregon's answer probably won't solve your issue, you still want to rewrite your view code as in his snippet - you should only try to validate and save forms on POST requests.

Comment: I am already post my template

Comment: ok. Please try those two things: 1/ remove the ` | crispy` filter from your template (to make sure you don't have an issue with this), and 2/ add some trace (`logging` if you have setup your loggers - if you didn't, you should - or just simple `print("here")` calls) at the beginning of your view to make sure you really enter your view code (might be some urlconf issue).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```py
def edit(request,pk):
    child=get_object_or_404(Child_detail,pk=pk)
    form = ChildForm(instance=child)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=ChildForm(request.POST,instance=child)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('child')
    context={
        'form':form,
        'child':child
    }    
    return render(request,'functionality/edit.html',context)
```

Comment: While I totally agree on the suggested change (your snippet is indeed the one correct way to write such a view), I really doubt it will solve the OP's issue.

Comment: I am discover that i post a wrong code in ***views*** file that is why i get the different result,so the question is edited in views file

Comment: @jackson Can you please also add the code for your AcademicForm form please? If fields won't show then perhaps the error lives there.

Comment: Hi @jackson, what I see so far are two things: 1) I've never used the 'fields' parameter from the Meta class in a ModelForm as a tuple, please try changing it to a list "fields = ['Class', ...". And 2) I think you are declaring fields on that list that are not defined, neither in the Model nor in the Form itself, like Average_position and Total_number_in_class, please try removing them first from the 'fields' and 'label' parameters of the Meta class in your form, if that works, you need to define those extra fields in your form: "Overal_position = forms.CharField(...), etc.". Let me know.